# Latex decimal and thousand seperator with dot and comma

Tags: latex, separator

I have the following code currently used to separation in my report:

```
\sisetup{input-ignore={.},
     group-separator = {.},
     input-decimal-markers={,}, 
     output-decimal-marker = {,}}
```

What I want is examples as `\SI{5,7}{W}, \SI{42,2}{W}, \SI{100,5}{W} \SI{1.000}{W} and \SI{100.000}{W}.`
Comma should be the decimal separator while dot should be the thousand separator.

To clarify any possible misunderstanding the following is happening:

```
\SI{5,7}{W} = 5,7 W
\SI{42,2}{W} = 42,2 W
\SI{100,5}{W} = 100,5 W
\SI{1.000}{W} = 1000 W
\SI{100.000}{W} = 100.000 W
```

Currently I get everything except the `\SI{1.000}{W}` example. When I type `\SI{1.000}{W}` in my report the dot does not show up.

Comment: Please make a [mre] instead of these code fragments. You're probably looking for `group-four-digits`

Comment: Maybe a question for https://stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

By default, the minimum number of digits for a group separator to be applied, is 5.

In siunitx v3 or newer, you can change this setting with `group-minimum-digits=4`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{input-ignore={.},
     group-separator = {.},
     input-decimal-markers={,}, 
     output-decimal-marker = {,},
     group-minimum-digits=4
     }

\begin{document}

\SI{5,7}{W} = 5,7 W

\SI{42,2}{W} = 42,2 W

\SI{100,5}{W} = 100,5 W

\SI{1.000}{W} = 1000 W

\SI{100.000}{W} = 100.000 W

\end{document}
```